# C++ condition_variable cin and cout

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, iostream

I have tried to implement `condition_variable` with two threads, the following code would work well if I don't use user input (`std::cin`), but once I used it, the program crashed after I input a number on screen.

Why does it crash?

```
std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cond;
int x =0;
void th_in()
{
  std::unique_lock <mutex> locker(mu);
  std::cin>>x;
  locker.unlock();
  cond.notify_all();
}
void th_out()
{
  std::unique_lock <mutex> locker(mu);
  cond.wait(locker);
  std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
  locker.unlock();
}

int main()
{    
  std::thread t2(th_out);
  std::thread t1(th_in);    
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side info: `std::condition_variable` may cause "spurious wakeup", so `cond.wait(locker);` will be unblocked when `th_in` does not invoke `cond.notify_all();`. See also [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because your program is exiting when you give input (`std::cin.get()`) and you are not detaching the threads or joining them.

In *Concurrency in Action* by [Anthony Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5597/anthony-williams), it is stated that `std::thread::join` or `std::thread::detach` must be called explicitly before the `std::thread` object is destroyed, else `std::terminate` will be called.

Hence, the crash.

---

You can fix it by having `int main` wait for the threads to finish execution:

```
int main() {
    std::thread t2(th_out);
    std::thread t1(th_in);

    t2.join();
    t1.join();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This should be safer. This also resolves the problem invoked by having 2 threads blocked by `std::cin`.